# PHP select MySQL column from query using users input

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table which is something like this:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Weight  | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 100     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 120     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 130     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 150     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 160     | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I select a Row using

```
$row = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Rates WHERE Weight<='$weight' AND Weight>='$weight'");
```

My question is using the returned query result how do I print the value of one of the Fields (100, 120, 130, 150, 160) which is closest to what the user enters.

For example is the user types in 110 the value in the field '120' would be printed.
Or if 131 was entered the value of '150' would be printed (so always rounded up).

As it stands I have:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rate))
    {
        echo "Using weight your cost is: " . $row['100'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

But this only prints the value of the field '100'
How would I replace this to take the users input and work out which of the rows are closest and print that

So something like:

```
IF ($value =< 100) echo $row['100']
IF ($value =< 120 && $value > 100) echo $row['120']
IF ($value =< 130 && $value > 120) echo $row['130']
..etc
```

Comment: Please, read up on [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) because what you're doing here with string interpolation can cause **severe problems**. It's extremely important to [properly escape any and all user data](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysqli` supports parameterized queries which should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Rates
order by abs(Weight - $weight)
limit 1;
```

This returns one row, where the weight is closest to the user value.

The following version always rounds up:

```
SELECT *
FROM Rates
WHERE Weight >= $weight
order by Weight
limit 1;
```

EDIT:

Based on your edit, I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT (case when "100" >= $value then "100"
             when "120" >= $value then "120"
             when "130" >= $value then "130"
             when "150" >= $value then "150"
             when "160" >= $value then "160"
        end)
FROM Rates
WHERE Weight<='$weight' AND Weight>='$weight';
```

The `case` chooses the first matching value.

Comment: sorry I guess I wasnt clear, the right weight it selected but I then need to print out the right field from that row depending on a second value the user enters

Comment: +1. @ZacPowell: It's a `select *` query. it's retrieving ALL of the fields in the row that has the closest weight. If you want another field, then just `echo $row['the_other_field']`

Comment: @MarcB yes I see that but my issue is that the field printed need to be one which is closest to the users value rounded up

Comment: which is exactly what the second query is doing.

Comment: @MarcB I guess I am not explaining right, the right weight row is already selected its then working out which field to display I need help with

Comment: ah. I see. you've got a wonky table setup... You need to normalize that design and put your weights into a separate sub table. What you want cannot be done nicely with a simple query, since you've got multiple fields holding different values in the same record. Exactly what are you storing in that `150` and similar fields?

Comment: @MarcB Ah ok I see what you mean '150' and similar fields are storing prices for that distance with at that weight

Comment: then definitely put them into a sub table, e.g. `weight_distances (weight, price)` or something like that. then you can use the above answer by adding a simple join the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version.

```
SELECT *
FROM Rates
WHERE Weight>='$weight'"
limit 1;
```

It will return only one row. you can fetch value as

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rate);
echo "Using weight your cost is: " . $row['Field'];
echo "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an `if/else` block to set your field -

```
if($your_value <= 100) {$field = 100;}
else if($your_value <= 120) {$field = 120;}
else if($your_value <= 130) {$field = 130;}
else if($your_value <= 150) {$field = 150;}
else {$field = 160;}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rate))
{
    echo "Using weight your cost is: " . $row[$field];
    echo "<br>";
}
```